# How to get incoming calls when app is in kill state in Android with Twilio SDK?

Tags: android, twilio

I am trying to implement [Twilio SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) and i have done it, It is working fine when APP is in memory not killed..
Now I have to implement Twilio to get calls any time if my app is is killed or not.
How can i achieve this like by any service in background or any other solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible. You need to check that If twillo is making call and your app is in background. What kind of even you can fetch from android system using broadcast receiver. And after getting success from that broadcast receiver. you can call your service of twillo and you can show to user.

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked with twillo api, but you can achieve events of calling from android system using following code. You should try this out.

To register Broadcast Receiver, write below codes in **AndroidMainifest.xml** file.

```html
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

to give phone state permission to your app use below code in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Below is Broadcast Receiver

```html
public class PhoneStateReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {


  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try 
     {
        System.out.println("Receiver start");
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
         if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){   
          Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is -"+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
        if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))){
          Toast.makeText(context,"Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
          Toast.makeText(context,"Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }catch (Exception e){ 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answering Gulnaz but the your answer is not even Related to my question the twilio works over VOIP.

Comment: Are you able to get any event when call comes in your app?